# update a page after closing a ui:include dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My page call a page as a dialog after clicking a commandButton, after filling the form i would like after submitting that form and closing that page to update a field in the page that called ui:include.
I can't seem to achieve that.

Comment: Did you actually try to achieve that? Please consider reading [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use following  example and then your submit button should look like :

```
<p:commandButton value="OK"
      update="your_root_page_id" action="yourAction()" />
```

Comment: Thanks, refactored a bit;)